# The meaning of 'as easy as not'

Tags: meaning

The passage below comes from Emily's runaway imagination by Beverly Cleary.

> The ride back to town was peaceful enough, although Emily was a little
>   nervous lest they meet a cow in the middle of the road that might
>   force them to stop. It would be awful if they had to stop now after
>   all she had been through. When they came to Main Street, she said, “I
>   can walk home from the store, Grandpa, ***as easy as not***.”

Could you explain to me the meaning '***as easy as not***'?

And if you don't mind, give me another example sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means there are two options of equal value.

In your quote, Emily pretends she could continue to ride with everybody, or walk, it is all the same to her.

> I could pick up your mail for you while you're gone, **as easy as not**.

This means that while you're away on business, I could pick up your mail for you - or not; it's all the same to me.

Comment: Thanks. It was helpful for me. What about "As easy as that."?